# Could a plane with an electric turbine engine generate enough lift to get to space?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, fluid-dynamics, electricity, kinematics, aerodynamics

This question is similar to my previous ones but configuration is different and so is the question.

Could a modified electric turbine engine (E-Fan) plane create enough of it's own lift not to burden an electric rail that is evenly supported by electric powered blimps and rail (similar to a 3rd rail of a train) while carrying a payload (like the space shuttle) to the edge of space? The problem with a high power electric engine is the is the supply of electricity and weight of the engine and battery . The blimps and rail are necessary to provide the amount needed without a huge battery. Rockets still can be used at the end of it.

[image]

Comment: None of your questions seem to show an understanding that getting into a sustained orbit is very different from just getting above the atmosphere. Rockets to orbit only spend a minute or so in the thick atmosphere, but after that they have to accelerate for about 25 minutes more to reach the high speed necessary to stay up. [*Read this.*](http://www.explainthatstuff.com/spacerockets.html)

Comment: @MikeDunlavey This is only an alternative to booster rockets.

Comment: @MikeDunlavey if this rail is attached when something goes wrong the blimps would lower the remains slower than falling.

Comment: If something went wrong it would do so catastrophically: you've given them things to *hit*. High-speed trains derail when their tracks deviate by only a few cm over the length of a car from the expected alignment, and they are only going a few hundred kph. Required comic: http://www.smbc-comics.com/?id=3766

Comment: @Jen: Then you might restate your question along the lines of: What are launch alternatives to large expensive booster rockets? and show some research such as launch from aircraft, re-usable rockets, skyhook, and the pros and cons of a floating rail.